# Splitting text into separate fuctions

Tags: r, format

I have a spreadsheet in "R" where a column is a full Name (last name, first name middle name) ex Thompson, Billy Red. I am trying to run a function that separates that operates them and will produce only first name.

Example code that I am using. I need the "get_first_name" created any ideas?

top.25 <- head( d$Full.Name,25 )

first.25 <- get_first_name( name=top.25 )

data.frame( top.25, first.25 ) %>% pander()

Comment: Please include a `dput(top.25)` so we can see the format of the names.

Comment: As long as your names always have a `Last comma First Middle` sequence, then `separate(d, Full.Name, sep="[\\s,]+", into=c("Last", "First", "Middle"))` (assuming dplyr pipe) will work, but ... cases with no middle ("Smith, John"), some spaced last names ("St Croix, Some Body"), or similar will absolutely break the pattern. In which case ... join the queue of people wanting a regex to handle that gracefully, it's very prone to things like that.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
get_first_name <- function(x) {
   sub(" .*", "", sub(".*, ", "", x))}
```

Example:

```
Full.Name <- c("Thompson, Billy Red", "Smith, John", "St Croix, Some Body") 

get_first_name(Full.Name)
```

Result:

```
[1] "Billy" "John" "Some"
```

**Rationale:**

First, the function extracts everything that is after ", " (comma + space):

```
sub(".*, ", "", x)
```

Second, it extracts everything that is before " " (space):

```
sub(" .*", "", y)
```

Replace the first step as the "y" in the second step, and assign it to your function.